# What happens when you keep using a printer's imaging unit after end of life

Tags: printer

We have a Samsung M267x 287x Series printer. As per my past experience with monochrome laser printers, we refill the toner which is rated 3k 4 times and then get a new toner. Reason, a new toner costs 40$ vs a refill that costs 4$.

The printer has a separate toner and a separate imaging unit. The imaging unit is rated for 9k impressions. As our usage has crossed 9k impressions, the pritner was disabled.

Under machine settings in the web-utility, I can force the printer to keep printing. Coming to the main question, is it safe to run a 9k imaging untill 12k or should I stop printing and get the new imaging unit?

Apparently Samsung doesn't make the R116 anymore says my local re-seller. They have other OEM Imaging units.

Is there any way these imaging units can be reused by changing the drum?

Comment: If you cannot find spare parts from third parties and if the printer still works, force it to go further. You have nothing to lose.

Comment: You won't break your printer by forcing it. In the past no rules existed in printers' firmware - you could print 'til blank pages came out. Counters and toner sensors were always there, but had more of an informative than enforcing role (so you can buy them beforehand). Nowadays manufacturers enforce toner and / or imaging unit change at "optimal time", but oldtimers (like me) know they could print some more using existing materials. My Konica-Minolta also enforces imaing unit change but my friend from service said he'll reset the counter cuz it can go twice as long as maker says it will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no real problem in using an expired imaging unit, but 2 things can cause grief.

1. The printer's firmware may decide that it will not work with an expired IU. If that happens, there is nothing you can do except get a new IU.
2. Eventually the print quality will start to deteriorate. This is normally quite gradual, so you will get plenty of warning. At that stage you will again have to get a new IU.